# Complex casting

Tags: c, casting, linux-kernel, kernel-module

After learn C and theorical stuffs of operatives systems, i decided to analyze one kernel rootkit for linux, but i can't understand one line of code, i don't know how to read that line:

```
*(void **)&((char *)h->original_function)[ASM_HOOK_CODE_OFFSET] = h->modified_function;
```

Full context:

```
#if defined __i386__
    // push 0x00000000, ret
    #define ASM_HOOK_CODE "\x68\x00\x00\x00\x00\xc3"
    #define ASM_HOOK_CODE_OFFSET 1
    // alternativly we could do `mov eax 0x00000000, jmp eax`, but it's a byte longer
    //#define ASM_HOOK_CODE "\xb8\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xe0"
#elif defined __x86_64__
    // there is no push that pushes a 64-bit immidiate in x86_64,
    // so we do things a bit differently:
    // mov rax 0x0000000000000000, jmp rax
    #define ASM_HOOK_CODE "\x48\xb8\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xe0"
    #define ASM_HOOK_CODE_OFFSET 2
#else
    #error ARCH_ERROR_MESSAGE
#endif

struct asm_hook {
    void *original_function;
    void *modified_function;
    char original_asm[sizeof(ASM_HOOK_CODE)-1];
    struct list_head list;
};


/**
 * Patches machine code of the original function to call another function.
 * This function should not be called directly.
 */
void _asm_hook_patch(struct asm_hook *h)
{
    DISABLE_W_PROTECTED_MEMORY
    memcpy(h->original_function, ASM_HOOK_CODE, sizeof(ASM_HOOK_CODE)-1);
    *(void **)&((char *)h->original_function)[ASM_HOOK_CODE_OFFSET] = h->modified_function;
    ENABLE_W_PROTECTED_MEMORY
}
```

Rootkit link:
https://github.com/nurupo/rootkit/blob/master/rootkit.c
(line 314 of rootkit.c)

I don't want to be explained how the rootkit, only want to understand how to read that line of code, the first part of the line makes me dizzy.

Comment: @chux I'd be surprised to see an UB-free rootkit... (as for the question: Seriously, start learning C, by following a book, and coding your own simple programs, step by step. You will eventually reach a point that enables you to read such code as well)

Comment: First consult the [operator precedence table](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) and understand the order the operations are taking place here.

Comment: The follow up question would be why this `*(void **)&`?

Comment: @FelixPalmen I learn C in University, and recently i worked with OpenMPI 
for another matter, and i also made an small change in the kernel to add a systemcall for operating system matter, but anyway, lines of code like this are hard to understand for my, and it seems to me that this is the time to learn how to read comprex lines like this, by justly analyzing pieces of codes like this. Now that I went back to review the operator tables precedence, the lines begins to be clearer and i can still reading the rest of rootkit code.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Thanks for make me remember to query the operator precedence table! That helped me to better understand the code line

Comment: @chux Sorry, alk added it!

Answer (score 1):

If I am not mistaken: you start at the innermost part, which is

```
h->original_function
```

Then we see a brace at the right so now we scan left for the matching brace. But wait a second, we see a cast to `(char *)` so it is a pointer to a char and now the brace closes.

On the right we now see an array indexing to take element `[ASM_HOOK_CODE_OFFSET]` and on the left we now see `&` to take its address. So we now have the address of a char.

Now we can only go the the left and see `*(void **)`, which casts this address to be a pointer-to-a-pointer-to-void and then dereference it and assign the right part to the address.

Comment: This approach is referred to as [the Spiral Rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html)

Comment: @EdwardMinnix, thanks, didn't know it had that name.